# Convert Byte array to string to post to syslog

Tags: c, arrays, string, hex

I have an array that looks like this:

```
u_int8_t arr[10] = {0x02, 0x0A, 0x01 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x09, 0x03};
```

At present I have a function to print this array to the terminal, it works like this:

```
void dump_packet(void* packet, int len)
{
u_int8_t* bytes = (u_int8_t*)packet;
int i = 0;
while (i < len){
    printf("%02X-", bytes[i++]);
    fflush(stdout);
}

printf("|");
}
```

So on the screen I see : `02-0A-01-01-00-00-01-00-09-03-|`. I was wondering how I would go about altering this function so that the packet was stored as a string in the format above? I would like to do this so I can write the packets I receive to the `syslog`.

Comment: How about [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)?

Comment: Thanks, kind of new to C, so not too familiar with all the string related functions. These will do nicely!

Comment: @Kells1996 - you can use char* tmp to store part of string every time and append to that tmp using strcat. You might need to do typecasting to char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the suggestion of Joachim Pileborg and edited my `dump_packet` function to look like this:

```
void dump_packet(void* packet, int len)
{
u_int8_t* bytes = (u_int8_t*)packet;
int i = 0;
char hex[10];
char hexstring[4*MAXBUFSIZE] = "";


while (i < len){
    sprintf(hex, "%02X-", bytes[i]);
    strcat(hexstring, hex);
    printf("%02X-", bytes[i++]);
    fflush(stdout);
}
printf("|");
syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s", hexstring);
}
```